# iPhone UIBarButtonItem alpha of button image

Tags: iphone, image, uibarbuttonitem, alpha

I've added a button to a lower toolbar like this:

```
UIImage *locationImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"193-location-arrow.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *locationButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:locationImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(updateCurrentLocation)];

NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:locationButton,nil];
[toolbar setItems:items];
[items release];
[locationButton release];
```

This works great, the alpha of the image is picked up fine, the button displays like this:

[image: Location Icon]

So, I took this code and modified slightly to create a button in my navigation bar:

```
UIImage *favouriteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"28-star.png"];

UIBarButtonItem *favouriteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:favouriteImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = favouriteButton;

[favouriteButton release];
```

The alpha doesn't seem to be picked up on this one - it looks greyed out:

[image]

Is there something I need to set when using custom images in the navigation bar?

Thanks and Regards,

Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the image to white with a few lines of code:

```
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height)
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data1, imageRect.size.width, imageRect.size.height, 8, imageRect.size.width * 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGContextClipToMask(context, imageRect, inImage.CGImage);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
CGContextFillRect(context, imageRect);

CGImageRef finalImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage *returnImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:finalImage];       

CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGImageRelease(finalImage);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I'd like to know why the two act differently though? Just for my own curiosity's sake! Any ideas?

Comment: UIBarButtonItem isn't technically a UIView subclass, it's just a data structure - the actual presentation of UIBarButtonItems is up to the toolbar / other view that's displaying them.Not 100% sure why Apple chose to apply that white-ifying filter in buttons in UIToolbars but not UINavigationBars, but I've seen the same problem here so you're not imagining it.